# WCF Post with JSON

Tags: c#, wcf, post

Very strange scenario happens with me

when I try to post **something** to the WCF method and this **something** has \r as two separate characters actually I send "domain\machine" to the WCF.

The strange thing is that the machine name starts with R so the string I send is
"domain\r****" so when WCF receives it it asssumes I want to send \r which stands for line feed character so it replace it with single character. any hint how to avoid this?

This is the function signature

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate = "json/listServer")]
Response ListShares(Request request);
```

Request is a data contract class that has only one data member ServerName which is of type string.

Comment: Do you know how to escape special characters? That's all you need to do..

Comment: I send "my domain\\relativemachine" and post this to the web method

in the debugger I found that the WCF method received "my domain\relativemachine" as it converts \\r which is two characters to \r which is a single character

Comment: Try `"domain\\r"` or `@"domain\r".

Comment: Guys I do escape special characters and confirmed that from the client debugger. I guess the other part on the server that parse the JSON has a bug or something

Comment: The simple solution would be to split the single field into two fields, `DomainName` and `MachineName`, and assemble it manually on the server.

Comment: I want to avoid that because the client get this format from another WCF method and I want to avoid manipulating the string on the client side as it will be designed for mobile

Comment: It seems you form your string manually. Use a json parser(Json.Net, JavasSriptSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer etc.) to form your json string not to deal with escaping special characters,

Comment: that is what I ended to use. but sending path to WCF will require you to send each backslash twice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some unknown reason to send \ in the the POST method to WCF web method you need to send it as \\\\ because JSON parser on the WCF side will try to find any escape characters followed by it!!